# OTP (token) should be automatically read from the message,

Tags: ionic3, one-time-password

I have a Register  page on which user enter their mobile number, after receiving the One-time password i want to verify the One-time password automatically by reading the One-time password. but i am not able to do that because i cannot find the suitable example.

So if anybody knows how to do it please share it. I badly need the advice, i want to do it immediately.

Is it possible using  **ionic 3**?

Comment: tag added and question formatted.

Answer (score 0):

1. First install Android permission plugin for reading SMS from message app.

> $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
>
> $ npm install --save @ionic-native/android-permissions

2. Set android permission request in component.ts file

```html
this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_SMS, 
      this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.RECEIVE_SMS,this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SMS]).then(status => {
        console.log('All Has permission?=>',status.hasPermission);
    },err => {
      console.log('All Has permission Failed=>',status);
    });
```

3. Install this plugin for reading OTP from a message.

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sms

4. Declear SMS variable like this => **declare var SMS;** in your OTPVerification.ts file
5. Create one method for watch your text message activity. And call this method when you send OPT message on your device.

```html
UpdateMethod(){
  if(SMS) SMS.startWatch(function(){
    console.log('watching', 'watching started');
  }, function(){
    console.log('failed to start watching');
  });

  document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e:any){
    var sms = e.data;
    // Here you get your message
    console.log(sms);
  });
}
```